# Chromecast MediaInfo.Builder can't play shoutcast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, shoutcast

I have one problem regarding MediaInfo.Builder of Google Cast. I used following code:

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://shoutcast2.index.uz.zgora.pl:8000")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
                .build();
```

But Cast player is not working at all. The reason is, that URL leads to SHOUTCAST. Apparently, the problem is in content type. Could somebody advise which contentType to use for shoutcast streams, or at least provide some workaround for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `http://shoutcast2.index.uz.zgora.pl:8000/`, use `http://shoutcast2.index.uz.zgora.pl:8000/;`.  Note the semicolon on the end.

SHOUTcast servers are going to look for `Mozilla` in the `User-Agent` request header, as a way of detecting a browser vs. a media player.  If the server thinks the client is a browser, it will send the admin page rather than the stream.  By passing `;` in the request URI, the SHOUTcast server will use the user agent string of `MPEG OVERRIDE` and will send the actual stream data.

You should also know that SHOUTcast isn't truly HTTP compatible.  It's close enough that it will probably work, but may stop working in the future.  Icecast is one of several better alternatives.

Comment: I tried this and the solution is not working. Maybe something else has to be set as well. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Tom11 Could be anything, but without knowing the specifics of what you mean by "not working", it isn't possible to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Brad's solution worked for me. Just added a slash and a semicolon after the port. I also changed the content type from `audio/mpeg` to `audio/mp3`. My working code looks like this.

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder("http://shoutcast2.index.uz.zgora.pl:8000/;")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                .build();
```

Comment: Your content type is wrong.  `audio/mpeg` is what it's supposed to be.  `audio/mp3` isn't valid.